# Ignore case in ORDER BY in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

I came across a situation where i want to sort the mysql query result in alphabetical order ignoring the case... I mean

```
Al

aasd

Cfds 

ddafsf
```

...

I found a solution where convert every element of the result into either lower or upper case and use **Order By** ..I didnt like this approach... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html .. Read this article..... But i grasped nothing...Just wanna know how can this be done... cheers...

Comment: on what OS is your `MySQL` server installed?

Comment: You got the wrong document. Read [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-general.html) and ongoing chapters instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not use `ASC` directly,

```
SELECT *
FROM   tableName
ORDER  BY columnName ASC
```